# Manage permissions with Facebook JS SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a list of fb permissions that I want to select / deselect and then I want to submit the changes to facebook with this logic **with just one user action** ( one click ):

**1)** login to FB;

**2)** delete ( revoke ) all permissions;

**3)** request the new ( selected ) permissions.

```
<button onclick="changePermissions()">Change permissions</button>

function changePermissions() {
        FB.login((response) => {

            FB.api('/me/permissions', 'DELETE', () => {

                FB.login(() => {}, {
                    scope: 'email,publish_pages', // the new selected permissions
                    auth_type: 'rerequest'
                });
            });
        });
}
```

Step **1)** and **2)** works as expected, but step **3)** fails. ( the new login pop-up with the new permissions is blocked by the browser ). Facebook js sdk says that "FB.logion() must be called from button event handler".

How can I achieve this scenario with just one user action ( 1 click ). I don't want to force the user to interact multiple times with the UI in order to change his permissions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user authorized your App already, you can just delete the permissins BEFORE `FB.login`. `FB.getLoginStatus` re-authorizes the user anyway. So the first FB.login is not needed, but the API call for deleting permissions is ansynchronous, that is why browser block the second `FB.login` call.
**Just delete the permissions right after FB.getLoginStatus and only do `FB.login` in the `changePermissions` function.**

Example with `FB.getLoginStatus`: https://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: yes, but this is done with more then one action, I need 1 action ( to click a button in order to revoke the permissions and then FB.login() with the new permissions )

Comment: no, it is one user action only. you do not call FB.getLoginStatus on user interaction, you use it on page load only.

Comment: yes, I get that...but in this solution the delete-permissions and request-permissions (  FB.login() ) are decoupled. I need to handle those two in one place.

Comment: that is not possible, fb.login needs to be called on user interaction, not in an asynchronous callback